# JavaScript - Conteúdo de uma TD comparando com uma variável

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um script que limpa os 3 elementos a seguir. 
No If a clausula tem que cair no verdadeiro (Fiz a consulta através do console.log e tem que cair no verdadeiro, porém cai na posição false. 
Podem me ajudar a descobrir o porque??

```js
 function teste(){
     var idAntigo = "123"
        var tds = document.querySelectorAll("#tblItens td");
        var values = [];
        var tabela = document.querySelector("#tblItens");
        var TDs1 = tabela.getElementsByTagName("td");
        console.log("Caiu aqui");
        for (i = 0; i < TDs1.length; i++) {
        console.log("Aqui também");
            if (TDs1[i].innerHTML === idAntigo ) {
        console.log("Aqui não");
                TDs1[i].innerHTML = "";
                TDs1[i + 1].innerHTML = "";
                TDs1[i + 2].innerHTML = "";
                TDs1[i + 3].innerHTML = "";
                break;
            } else { console.log("false")}
        }
    }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 <table id="tblItens">
  <tr>
   <td> 123 </td>
   <td> 124 </td>
   <td> 123 </td>
  </tr>
   <td> 123 </td>
  <tr>
   <td> 125 </td>
   <td> 124 </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <button onclick="teste()"> teste </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: (TDs1[i].innerHTML === TDs1) nunca vai ser verdadeiro, você está comparando a td atual com o objeto que armazena todas as td´s, o que você realmente quer fazer nessa parte?

Comment: Perdão @Felipe, a comparação deve comparar o elemento da td com a `idAntiga`, ainda sim nem cai no If, corrigi a pergunta lá, perdão novamente

Comment: Ata entendi seu problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repare que os elementos na td estão com um espaçamento, o `innerHTML` pega esse espaçamento, e ao fazer a verificação isso vai interferir, uma alternativa é o `innerText` que pega somente a área do texto, exemplo...

```js
function teste(){
     var idAntigo = "123"
        var tds = document.querySelectorAll("#tblItens td");
        var values = [];
        var tabela = document.querySelector("#tblItens");
        var TDs1 = tabela.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (i = 0; i < TDs1.length; i++) {
            if (TDs1[i].innerText == idAntigo ) {
            console.log("agora caiu");
                TDs1[i].innerHTML = "";
                TDs1[i + 1].innerHTML = "";
                TDs1[i + 2].innerHTML = "";
                TDs1[i + 3].innerHTML = "";
                break;
            } else { console.log("false")}
        }
    }
```

```html
<table id="tblItens">
  <tr>
   <td> 123 </td>
   <td> 124 </td>
   <td> 123 </td>
  </tr>
   <td> 123 </td>
  <tr>
   <td> 125 </td>
   <td> 124 </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <button onclick="teste()"> teste </button>
```

Comment: Ah, entendi !! Obrigado pela explicação e pela ajuda @Felipe !!